# glGetIntegerv returning 36064

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have a Qt application with a `QOpenGLWidget`. In that widget I have my OpenGL functions, which are rendering my scene as I expect.

Among those rendering instructions I put the following lines with which I'm getting an unexpected result:

```
void MyOpenGLVisualizer::paintGL()
{
    GLint my_val = 0;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_DRAW_BUFFER, &my_val);
    std::cout << my_val << std::endl;
    ...
}
```

These lines print: `36064` which is `0x8ce0`. But according to [glGet documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glGet.xml) I would expect it to return: `GL_FRONT` which is `0x0404` or `GL_BACK` which is `0x0405`.

I've invoked `glGetError()` after those lines, but it returns `0`.

I thought maybe the return value was an Or-ed combination of these macros, but that would contain all of them:  `GL_BACK`, `GL_FRONT`, and other bits.

So, what does that `36064` mean?

(In case it helps, I'm using the OpenGL wrappers of Qt: `QOpenGLFunctions`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an unfortunate consequence of reading the OpenGL 2.0 manual pages, they do not reflect the modern API.

**0x8CE0** is `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`, which is a perfectly reasonable thing for that to return in OpenGL 3.0 or when using `GL_{ARB|EXT}_framebuffer_object`. You will find this documented in the OpenGL 4.0 manual page, which you can reference [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glDrawBuffer.xhtml).

`glGet (...)` is not actually documenting all of the possible returned values, mind you. It is actually telling you the default values, which are `GL_FRONT` for a single-buffered framebuffer and `GL_BACK` for a double-buffered.

You need to refer back to the `glDrawBuffer (...)` API reference for a list of all valid values. And strangely, the GL 3.0 manual pages omit `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0`. The actual specification, which can be found [here](https://www.opengl.org/registry/) is considerably more thorough, but will probably overwhelm you unless you know what you are looking for.

Comment: I assumed my OpenGL version was 2, as when I execute this `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` I get: `2.1 NVIDIA-10.0.19 310.90.10.05b12`. So how do I find out my OpenGL version ?

Comment: @Mondkin: That is your GL version, but Qt is using the `GL_{ARB|EXT}_framebuffer_object` extension for something. Are you using Qt's Framebuffer class?

Comment: I wasn't doing it explicitly, but checking at the [docs of QOpenGLWidget](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qopenglwidget.html#details) it says: "All rendering happens into an OpenGL framebuffer object." Is that the same Qt framebuffer you are referring to?

Comment: @Mondikin: Yes, that is the one. And that explains why your draw buffer is a color attachment. It's drawing into an FBO instead of directly to the window.